# Touching A Tanach Before Netilat Yadayim

Tags: torah-study, tanach, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, netilat-yadayim-washing, chumash

Can one touch a Tanach, not Torah scroll, before doing netilat yadayim?

Comment: Todah @Kazibácsi

Comment: According to Shulchan Aruch Harav ([here](https://he.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3152640#v7) and [here](https://he.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3268360#v5)), before washing you're not supposed to walk, learn, say blessings, or touch parts of your body, your clothes, food or drink. I don't think it's too much of a stretch to say it would be inappropriate to touch holy objects. See also footnote 71 [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/34-practical-qa-on-restrictions-2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ([Berakhot 22a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.22a.8)):

> אָמַר לֵיהּ: בְּנִי, פְּתַח פִּיךָ וְיָאִירוּ דְבָרֶיךָ, שֶׁאֵין דִּבְרֵי תוֹרָה מְקַבְּלִין טוּמְאָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״הֲלֹא כֹה דְבָרִי כָּאֵשׁ נְאֻם ה׳״, מָה אֵשׁ אֵינוֹ מְקַבֵּל טוּמְאָה אַף דִּבְרֵי תוֹרָה אֵינָן מְקַבְּלִין טוּמְאָה.‏
>
> [Rabbi Yehuda ben Beteira] said to him: My son, open your mouth and let your words illuminate, as matters of Torah do not become ritually impure, as it is stated: “Is not my word like fire, says the Lord” (Jeremiah 23:29). Just as fire does not become ritually impure, so too matters of Torah do not become ritually impure.

See also [Chullin 136b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.136b.12), [Mishneih Torah Torah Tefillin, Mezuzah veSeifer Torah 10:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925432/jewish/Tefillin-Mezuzah-and-Sefer-Torah-Chapter-Ten.htm#v8), [Yoreh Deah 282:9](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%91_%D7%98).